# Programmatically login with Chromium Embeded

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

How to programmatically login in to a website with Chromium Embedded?
For example a website that has a login form like
facebook,gmail,yahoo etc..

Comment: You want the user to login by himself or you want to login programmatically? What problem are you encountering? What have you tried?

Comment: Just want to login programaticly myself ofcourse.

Comment: @kobik because people have too much to do i guess. This is why SO is flawed IMHO.. Everyone can down vote anyone..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TChromium.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript()` to execute some JavaScript to fill the form with the login info you have, then submit the form.